# Batch string manipulation with multiple special characters

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

I have a .txt file with many lines that look like...

```
Blah blah <spush><color:FFFF> name<spop> blah blah<spush> blah blah<spush><spop>.
```

In total spush and color appear 5 times and spop once in every line.

I am trying to write a batch file that removes all of that markup mess.

I can get basic string manipulation to remove a single instance of "" from a sentence if it only contains one instance by simply doing:

```
set "string=%string:<spush> =%"
```

but once the line contains multiples, I'm at a loss.

Comment: When handling with special characters, you should switch to delayed expansion, as that is safe against side effects of characters. Please show a minimal example with your code and describe where it fails

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying with plain batch. It's hard: `FOR` will remove empty lines, will ignore separators in beginning of line, will merge consecutive separators...

I would use PowerShell

```
(get-content x.txt) -replace "<.*?>",""`**
```

Comment: I would like to try using PowerShell, but said log files are in a game's folders, and has made everything read-only and require admin access.

My batch files work simply by running as admin, but PowerShell still gives me access denied errors.